# How to form URL in javascript along with user and account details as parameters to open it in new tab

Tags: javascript-remoting

I have an inline vf page with 3 inputtext fields and a commandbutton on account record. Now,when i click on commandbutton it should redirect to another URL. The URL contains current loggin user id and name and current account record id and 3 field values of vf page. See below for example.

http://prbi11.xyz.com:17063/GSSWaiverWeb/accountdetails.html?userId=1000123&fullName=Test&isAdmin=Y&accountId=33904194&pnrNumber=&firstName=&lastName=&isFromStart=true

in the above URL i gave test values.
vf page:

```
  <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
     <b> Waiver Management:  </b> 
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs1" columns="6">
         <apex:inputText id="Locator" label="Record Locator"  required="true"/>
         <apex:inputtext id="First" label="FirstName" required="true" />
         <apex:inputText id="Last" label="LastName" required="true"/>
          <apex:commandButton id="WaiverButton" value="Waiver Management"  style="background:#00008B; color:white; font-size: 13px;" onclick="getNameFields()"/> 
          <!--<apex:outputfield id="userid" value="{!currentuser.Id}"/>
          <apex:outputfield id="username" value="{!currentuser.Name}"/>-->
          <!--<apex:inputcheckbox label="GSS App User"/>
          <apex:inputCheckbox label="GSS App Admin"/>-->
          <apex:param name="userid" value="{$!currentuser.PPR_ID__c}"/>
          <apex:param name="username" value="{!currentuser.name}"/>
          <apex:param name="IsAdmin" value="{!currentuser.IsAdmin__c}"/>
          <apex:param name="accountid" value="{!currentrecord.id}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>

    <script>
function getNameFields()
{

<!--var userid=document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb.pbs1.userid}').value;-->

    console.log('Getting Val. ');
    if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb.pbs1.First}').value == '')  {
            alert('Please enter First Name');
        }

    else if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.myForm.pb.pbs1.Last}').value == '')
    {
        alert('Please enter Last Name');
        }
       else{

          <!--window.open('http://prbi11.delta.com:17063/GSSWaiverWeb/accountdetails.html?userId=12345&fullName=FullName&isAdmin=Y&accountId=33904194&pnrNumber=&firstName=&lastName=&isFromStart=true')-->
           <!--window.open('http://prbi11.delta.com:17063/GSSWaiverWeb/accountdetails.html?userid={!currentuser.id}&fullName={!currentuser.Name}&IsAdmin=Yes&AccountId={!currentrecord.Id}&pnrnumber=Locator.value&firstname=First.value&lastname=Last.value)-->
          <window.open('http://prbi11.delta.com:17063/GSSWaiverWeb/accountdetails.html?userid=userid.value&fullName=username.value&IsAdmin=IsAdmin.value&AccountId=accountid.value&pnrnumber=Locator.value&firstname=First.value&lastname=Last.value)
```

}

```
}
</script>
```

controller class:
public class WaiverManagementController {

```
public String username { get; set; }

public String userid { get; set; }

public String getAccountId { get; set; }

public Account currentRecord{get; set;}
public user currentuser{get; set;}

public WaiverManagementController() {

}

//String Waiver {get;}
 PageReference redirectURL()
 {
    PageReference myVFPage = new PageReference('https://google.com');
       myVFPage.setRedirect(true);
       // myVFPage.getParameters().put('myId', accId);
        return myVFPage;
    }



  public void userinfo(ApexPages.StandardController cont){
     //user=(User) cont.getRecord();
     //currentuser=new User();
     currentuser=[Select Id,Name,IsAdmin__c from User where Id=:userinfo.getuserId()];
```

}

```
    public void getAccountId() 
    {
        currentRecord = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

   }
```

Can any one please help me. Which is not working for me.(may be my approach is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code snippet to redirect to a particular link.

```
    var navigateURL;
    navigateURL = 'Your URL';   
    function isLightningExperienceOrSalesforce1() {
          `return((typeof sfo`rce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one));
        } 
        if( isLightningExperienceOrSalesforce1() ) {
              sforce.one.navigateToURL(navigateURL);
        }
        else{
              window.location.href = navigateURL;


}
```

Comment: Hi Subhasis,  my issues is i want to form  URL which takes those values as dynamically. if you see i tried in second else block of js function getNameFields(). But, its not forming the URL as expected. I mean user values, account id and vf page inputtext filed values to be get dynamically when its loaded.